# IntelliJ shows html validation error in jsp file on first "<c:"

Tags: maven, validation, jsp, intellij-idea, jstl

IntelliJ 2020.3.1 (Ultimate Edition) insists on showing me validation errors where there are none in a maven war project with a jsp. It does so on the first "<c:" of any jsp file. It doesn't complain about the jstl dependency being missing though (it isn't). It seems as though the html validator doesn't know it shouldn't validate this kind of tag.

[image: Screenshot of jsp file in IntellJ]

The problems tab show this error:

```
'!', '!=', '%', '&#', '&&', '&gt;', '&lt;', '*', '+', '+=', ',', '-', '.', '/', <, <=, <Literal>, '==', '>', '>=', IDENTIFIER, STRING_IDENTIFIER, and, div, empty, eq, ge, gt, le, lt, mod, ne, not, or, '|' or '||' expected, got ':'
```

I've created a [minimal testcase](https://github.com/Crydust/maven-web-jsp) which shows off this superfluous error in index.jsp.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem in IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.1 using the provided link. [See the screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/XgPJjxv.png). It looks like you've injected some different language fragment inside the `<body>` tag. Do you see the un-inject option in the [Alt+Enter menu](https://i.imgur.com/GLejZtu.png)? See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-language-injections.html for more details.

Comment: I just checked on another machine and indeed there are no errors there. Maybe I've installed a stricter html validating plugin on themachine where the problem is reproducible? I'll investigate later.

Comment: Notice the background color inside the body tag is different. Usually it indicates a language injection being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error goes away after disabling the bundled ThymeLeaf (version 203.6682.168) plugin. My project makes no mention of Thymeleaf, so I don't understand why it should validate my jsp files.

I've reported this as an [intellij issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-259075).

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce either. Try to do File - Invalidate Caches/restart.

Also, could you try by updating to Jakarta?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You might want to specify a Runtime scope for the JSTL dependency if your Servlet container doesn't support the [latest JSTL specification](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.jstl), which is 2.0. For instance, Tomcat 10 doesn't.

Sorry for the Glassfish dependency though - Jakarta doesn't ship TLDs in their JSP APIs, [apparently](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jstl-api/issues/141).

Tell me if it works!